# how to select based on an attribute then filter by :not selector?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I have these 2 elements and I want to select the first one of them based on :not selector. I can't use any of orders selectors like `first-child` because the DOM content is changing

HTML

```
 <input value="50">
 <input value="50" name="name2">
```

I'm doing this

```
 $('input[value="50"]:not(input[name="name2"])');
```

but I always get Error in the browser console

> *Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name="name2"]*

thanks.

---

EDIT: the attribute name in my example is not name I was making this

```
 :not(input[click-once disabled="disabled"])
```

I replaced it with name here in the question to simplify example. I'm sorry my mistake! . but I can't delete the question since it got an answer. sorry for wasting your time

Comment: it's working for me..... although `$('input[value="50"]:not([name="name2"])')` is enough

Comment: @PranavCBalan i'm sorry I have mistake in the atribute name. I'm going to delete the question. thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
     $('input[value="50"]').not('input[name="name2"]');
```

Comment: thank you. I was making a different attribute in my real example that is did the problem. thanks for your time